# Remove everything after the first dollar amount or the second line

Tags: regex

Basically I'd like to remove everything except the first price ($27.95) using regex. Any help would be awesome.

```
$27.95
Trending at $44.55


 .*
```

Thanks Pharaoh the above worked, but it's leaving "Trending" behind. How do I remove new line?

Comment: I couldn't understand you! please explain

Comment: I basically want to remove everything after the first space. Which will leave me with $27.95

Comment: you want it in python? it's very simple

Comment: I need it in regex

Comment: sorry I don't know regex

Comment: Thanks anyways man

Comment: check this out http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=649721 good luck

Comment: What kind of regex? There are some differences in different languages. Have your read [ask] a good question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said different things in your question.

Each pattern is to be replaced by `''`, i.e. nothing.

- Remove everything after the first dollar amount: `(?<=\d)[^\d.].*`
  The actually removes everything, starting with the first non-digit (except a dot) that follows a digit, so while it works with your example, there can be no digits before the first price.
- Remove everything after the first space: `(?<=\s).*`
- Remove everything after the first space, including the space: `\s.*`

If you want to match just the price:

- `\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?`
   Use just the first match.
- If the first price always is the first thing in the string: `^\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?`
  This only matches the first price.

Each underscore is to be read as a space character - the markdown wouldn't let me write a space in the last pattern.

Comment: The first piece did nothing, but the second actually removed the first price which I want to keep and get rid of everything else.

Comment: I just want to keep...     $27.95

Comment: Testcases with your example: [First](https://regex101.com/r/8me4pC/1), [Second](https://regex101.com/r/TmyOaY/1) and [Third](https://regex101.com/r/BfUHtv/1).

Comment: Btw my black cat's name is Pharoah. Anywayz..... shouldn't the price I want to keep be highlighted? Noob here.

Comment: No, because you replace everything that is highlighted by nothing. If you want to match it, that's a different thing. I edited your question (the example was formatted badly) and added an option in my answer.

Comment: I see. Yes I'm trying to match it.

Comment: Thanks Pharaoh, the third option worked just had to remove space and add tab. Works great! https://regex101.com/r/BfUHtv/2